# Stop ajax from refetching data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a chat system like facebook. I want to load only data associated with a specific user into the user box that pops up. Just like facebook, a chat box pops up when someone clicks on the name of the user on the userlist on the sidebar (Hope I make sense). 
Everything is working fine but when I try to fetch data, the data keeps 'repeating itself'. 
Here are my codes for opening the chat box and fetching the data.

```
$('li.user').click(function(){
    id = $(this).data('id');
    _status = $(this).data('status');
    username = $(this).data('username');
    _return = false;
    $('.chat .chat-boxes .box').each(function(){
      if($(this).data('id') == id){
        $(this).find('.box-footer .textarea').focus();
        _return = true;
     }
  });
  if (_return){
    return
  };
  $('.chat').find('.chat-boxes').append(box.format(id,_status,username));
    $('.box').each(function(){
        _boxBody = $(this).find('.box-body');
        _messagesBox = $(this).find('.messages');
        _id = $(this).data('id');
        _messagesBox.append('This is Box #'+_id);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: base+'chat/getMessages.php',
            data: {'user2' : _id},
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){$('.box-body-top').html('Loading...')},
            success: function(res){
                if(res.success){

                }
                else if(res.fail){

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `repeating`? It's a bit critical.

Comment: For example see the line 
    _messagesBox.append('This is Box #'+_id);
When I click on the user once, it appends, say This is Box #12
When I click on another user, it appendsa 'This is Box #12This is Box #12' (twice). And the cycle continues

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused because your wrapped your Ajax request inside a loop.

```
$(".box").each(function( index ) { ... });
```

If more than one element with box class attached exists this is the amount of requests you can expect. Easy way to check it out would be in Developer Tools under Network tab and see how many requests are made.

You should also consider using sockets for chat system like this. Have a look at socket.io for example.

Comment: i need to implement it with jquery

Comment: In that case, follow what I said except the last paragraph. You've definitively got more than one .box element and your code is just iterating over that every time on click. Note, that it will iterate over the whole document not just the selected DOM from the click event.

Comment: Still not getting the desired results

Comment: You're really not providing a lot of information to help you. Did you follow my steps?  Is more than one request being made?

Maybe update your code to reflect changes you've made so we all can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @MahdiY, please explain the edit? I was referring to OPs code, not it doesn't refer to it as you've put a parameter inside the function

Comment: @Adriani6 It's same. just added simple code after it and put code in snippets format. your code haven't wrong.